# Even reveal with butt hinges and inset doors

Tags: hinges

I want to build a cabinet with a face frame and inset doors. I want to have a 3mm even reveal on every side of the door. The hinges are also 3mm thick. How do I achieve an even reveal?

Comment: 3mm is really large for a cabinet! That's the kind of gapping I'd expect to see around a room door. But to address your query, how is an even reveal achieved in any other context?

Comment: @Graphus what size of the reveal would you suggest? I never built a cabinet, a door or used hinges but understand the width of the door should be the size of the opening minus 2x desired reveal on each side. But I dont know how hinges work. How deep shall I go when routing out for the hinges? If I route out 3mm on the frame and 3mm on the door, will I then get 0mm reveal on the hinge side and 6mm reveal on the right side? Assuming the door is 6mm narrower than the opening.

Comment: For a cabinet I think you generally want to aim for 1/16" (*or less* for finer work). A 16th translates to 1.5mm, so nearly exactly half of what you were planning, and aiming for ~1mm reveals is pretty normal in cabinetmaking instruction over here.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks for pointing this out before I started cutting.

Comment: Are you absolutely stuck on an inset door? A modest overlay is ***much*** more forgiving. (And I say this as a working professional carpenter that has built kitchens from scratch with inset doors.)